# Does SuperObject in Delphi 2007 have problems with big JSON code?

Tags: json, delphi

I have an array of classes, where the size of each object can be from 1 KB to 1 MB. When parsing code, the created object is left blank. After some data searching, I came across an object that was smaller in size and the program worked without error. But when I copied the number of this object 7 times into the JSON array, the program got the same error again. But I did not have an error in parsing and reading SuperObject data with 6 copies.

Is there another SuperObject unit for Delphi 2007, or should I use `TJSONObject`?

```json
{
  "result": {
    "data": {
      "succeeded": true,
      "message": "",
      "data": [
        {...},
        {...},
        {...},
        {...},
        {...},
        {...},
        {...}
      ]
    },
    "status": {
      "statusCode": 200
    }
  },
  "status": {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "message": "OK"
  }
}
```